# How to convert a String to int array

Tags: javascript

I have a spring rest controller that returns an int array. But it is received as a String on the front-end.

How can I convert this String [1,1] to int array in Javascript.

edit: turns out, it was JSON.

Comment: exactly how is it responding? is it json?

Comment: @DanielA.White No it is not json. It is plain String.

Comment: As in "[1, 1]"?

Comment: no does it look like `String [1, 1]` or `[1, 1]`?

Comment: It is printed as `[1,1]` @Mihai

Comment: It is printed as `[1,1]` @DanielA.White

Comment: then thats valid json. use a json mechanism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string = `[1,1]`, then you can simply parse it as json.  Like this:

```js
const str = '[1,1]';
const resultArr = JSON.parse(str);

console.log(resultArr);
```

The result is an array of integers:

```
Array:
0: 1
1: 1
```

Comment: What will this give me? int array?

Comment: @FarazDurrani this will give you exactly what you want, give it a try

Comment: @FarazDurrani yes, it will be an array of integers.

Comment: what you want to do is get the string, i.e. `myString` and assign it to a variable, i.e. `myArray` like so: `var myArray = JSON.parse(myString);` then continue with the rest of your code on the front-end

Answer (score 2):

This is an example:

```
var arr = "[1, 1]".replace(/[\[\]]/g, "").split(",");
console.log(arr);
```

you can replace "[1, 1]" with you variable

Comment: that splits into strings.

Comment: @FarazDurrani this answer uses regex and javascript to find the desired pattern, in this case an array of integers, and replacing the string by an array. I agree it is not the optimal solution to your question, but it does the job